# How to resolve Perl module error while trying to run NGS QC Toolkit?

Tags: modules, perl, cpan

I was trying to run NGS QC Toolkit `http://59.163.192.90:8080/ngsqctoolkit/` in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64 bit version. But, after executing the command, an error shows that states it cannot find module `String::Approx` and needs to be installed even though I have installed it successfully.

Here is the command which I used:

```
perl ~/Programs/NGSQCToolkit_v2.3/QC/IlluQC_PRLL.pl -c 2 -pe /home/shrujan/Desktop/NGS_Shrujan/SRR072111_1.fastq /home/shrujan/Desktop/NGS_Shrujan/SRR072111_2.fastq 2 
A Error:
    Can not find module 'String::Approx'
    Install it and try again
```

Please guide me in resolving this issue.

Comment: Do you have the `libstring-approx-perl` package installed?

Answer (score 2):

Execute following commands:

```
shrujan@ubuntu:~$ cpan

cpan[1] install String::Approx
```

Then try your NGSQCTool